# How do I remove the minting authority from my custom token in Solana using @solana/web3.js?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, solana

I have been able to create custom tokens using custom wallets generated using `web3.Keypair.generate()`, but how do I now cap the supply of these tokens or remove the minting authority of these SPL tokens?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent any more minting, you'll need set the minting authority to `None`.  In JS, you can simply set the `newAuthority` to `null` during your call to `setAuthority` with `authorityType = MintTokens` in [1]

[1] https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/36e886392b8c6619b275f6681aed6d8aae6e70f9/token/js/client/token.js#L985

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jon Cinque's answer

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, Keypair, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token'
import * as bs58 from 'bs58';

(async () => {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'))

  const bytes = bs58.decode(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)
  const account = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bytes)

  const tokenMint = new PublicKey('EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v')
  const token = new Token(connection, tokenMint, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, account)

  await token.setAuthority(tokenMint, null, 'MintTokens', account.publicKey, [account])

})()
```